# What is the best way to delete old log data?

Tags: mysql

My service is writing text file logs and I would like to make a system to store log messages from text files into MySQL. I wrote a C# Console Application, which automatically parses text files with regex and run `INSERT` query. And what I have to do next is deleting old data(like older than 6 months) automatically.

I found that there is several ways to achieve this, but I could't determine what is the best way in real service.

1. Seperates the tables into partitions by month, then drop old partitions.
2. Makes a schedular which deletes old rows by `DATETIME` field(with `WHERE logDate < ...`).
3. Makes a table including the information of original text files. And makes foreign key from each log table which refers to `fileId`(primary key of file table). If I delete any row from file table then data having its `fileId` will be deleted cascadingly.

What will be the best solution? Or is there any idea that can help to choose one?

- I am using MySQL 8.0, and MyISAM for table engine.
- About 1M rows are inserted per day.

Comment: *About 1M rows are inserted per day.* - i.e. ~50k rows per hour. I'd prefer hourly event procedure which will delete the rows which are older than 6 months. But delete them not by datetime column but by autoincremented primary key value - this may improve the deletion slightly. Also you may need to run OPTIMIZE TABLE sometimes (for example, monthly) for to defragment the table.

Comment: The partitioning is not available on MyISAM on MySQL 8.0. But you may use MERGE Engine (MRG_MyISAM). Of course, there are a lot of disadvantages while comparing with partitioning, but it may be useful in your case nevertheless. Investigate: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html

Comment: @Akina - I used MERGE once, about 20 years ago.  I got burned when it bumped up against a 4GB limit that was unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` and use `DROP PARTITION` and `REORGANIZE PARTITION`.  Details here:  [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

I would use weekly partitions and have a cron (or EVENT) job running just before midnight to do the DROP and/or REORGANIZE when necessary.

Very efficient.  `DROP PARTITION` is orders of magnitude faster than `DELETE`.  Never need `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Your 3 options are currently ordered from best to worst.  (Cascading deleted sounds terrrrrible.)

In spite of what you might have read, use InnoDB, not MyISAM.  The disk footprint will be 2x-3x bigger, but power failures won't be a hassle.